# sed with string containing quote in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replacing some URLs in html files with the following line:

```
quote="\""
$(cd "$tutorials_dir_ios" && `sed -i '' 's#.png?version=.*$quote#.png#$quote#g' *.html`)
```

So this is supposed to match an URL like

```
someimage.png?version=123&some=thing"
```

and replace the part after .png until " occurs (I need to keep the " as tag closing in the html):

```
someimage.png"
```

But I'm getting:

```
sed: 1: "s#.png?version=.*$quote ...": bad flag in substitute command: '$'
```

I've tried some variations, also by using \x22 as double quote. This also throws:

```
sed: 1: "s#.png?version=.*\x22#. ...": bad flag in substitute command: '\'
```

I should mention that I'm running OS X, where sed has slightly different behavior.

What's the correct way to use a single quote using sed within a bash script? In a shell the same command using just a " works of course.

### Update

Fixed using double quotes meanwhile. But this is also not working:

```
$(cd "$tutorials_dir_ios" && `sed -i '' "s#.png?version=.*\"#.png#\"#g" *.html`)
```

gives

```
sed: 1: "s#.png?version=.*"#.png ...": bad flag in substitute command: '"'
```

Comment: Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, though that alone does not seem to be the issue. See the update.

Comment: You have too many `#` characters. It's `s#old#new#flags`. Why do you have `#` before the second backslash?

Comment: Thank you! My eyes are too tired... that was the problem.